# How did the three clones of Big Boss compare when it came to height?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series

I'd love to know the ratio of height between Solid Snake, Liquid Snake and Solidus Snake.

Was there ever any mention of height? (Like Liquid mentioning it when talking about being in Snake's shadow, etc.)

Were there any scenes where it could have been inferred visually?

Or is it even feasible that the clones could have differed in height from each other or Big Boss himself?

Comment: Do you mean "feasible" assuming cloning magically ages the clone to match the original? Usually, a clone could be of different height, because the environment can influence your height about 20-40%.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you're asking about their height? It seems kinda random, which means the question isn't likely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through various sources I have compiled the following bio stats, where they have got the stats from I'm unsure however:

- **Solid Snake** was 178cm in 1999. This was cited from `Metal Gear 2: Solid Snake - User's Manual, Konami Corporation (1990).`

  Interestingly he is also stated as 182cm from 2005-2014. This is cited from `The Mk.II displays this information on-screen in-game` and also the [Japanese Konami website](http://www.konami.jp/gs/game/mgs/character/ch01.html)
- **Liquid Snake** is 183cm cited from [Konami](http://www.konami.jp/gs/game/mgs/character/ch07.html)
- **Solidus Snake** doesn't list a height I'm afraid. I can't find anything from any notable sources.
- **Big Boss** is 192cm cited from [Konami entry for Big Boss](http://www.konami.jp/gs/game/mgs/character/ch20.html), but also stated as 180cm for 1999 cited from the same user manual as the 178cm entry for Solid Snake.

So really, being cloned seemed to f*ck shit up and make them grow a few inches between games. Big Boss grew 12cm between beginning of the series to the end, and he wasn't even a clone.

Comment: Why is do their heights change from 1999 to 2005? Retcons, that's why. Since Solidus is the "perfect" clone of Big Boss, I would imagine his height to be close to (if not the same as) him.

Comment: @QAzer but 180cm Big Boss or 192cm Big Boss?

Comment: I believe the latter (latest one) is a retcon.

Comment: The retcon is likely due (at least in part) to Japanese standards of height. Since their average height is shorter, they might have thought that those heights represented impressive or imposing figures. However, because Big Boss is American-born and thus his standards of "tall" should reflect American and not Japanese standards of "tall," they corrected it to be more in line with what is a "tall person" by American standards.

Answer (score 0):

Solid Snake is currently 5'11.5" or 182cm, Liquid is 6'0" or 183 cm, Big boss is 6'3" or 192 cm, Solidus as a guess is 6'2.5" or 189 cm, to compare only Solid is not 6' but very close.

Comment: Do you any sources?

Comment: have any sources* even

Comment: Yes on the metal gear wiki it lists them all expect Solidus which I took an educated guess being the perfect clone of Big Boss.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> is it even feasible that the clones could have differed in height from each other or Big Boss himself?

Les Enfants Terribles are not all perfect clones of Big Boss. Liquid Snake retains all of Big Boss's dominant genes, whilst Solid Snake has all of the recessive ones.

> Further genetic modification was carried out so that one clone would
>   express each of Big Boss's dominant genes, which were considered to be
>   inferior soldier genes [if 'super soldier genes' were dominant, this
>   project wouldn't be necessary], while the other would express his
>   recessive genes, which were intended to create a genetically superior
>   soldier. Because of the respective gene expressions, and the
>   mitochondrial DNA inherited from Dr. Clark's assistant, the twins had
>   a genetic difference of .43%,[4] enough of a difference to fool nearly
>   all DNA identification procedures exempting those that used precise
>   scanning.
>
> Nine months later, EVA gave birth to the so-called "Twin Snakes": the
>   clone considered to be genetically "superior", Eli, would later be
>   known as Liquid Snake, while the "inferior" clone, David, would be
>   known as Solid Snake.

Solidus is supposedly a perfect clone of Big Boss.

> Another clone of Big Boss was later secretly created, this time without modification to dominant/recessive gene expression, thus producing a "perfect clone." This clone would later be known as Solidus Snake (meaning neither solid nor liquid), whom the Patriots would consider a "perfectly balanced masterpiece."

These differences could potentially explain the differences in height.

Source: Games + http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Les_Enfants_Terribles

Alternatively.. differing smoking habits (or other environmental factors growing up) could be the explanation to stunted growth!

Answer (score -1):

- Big boss 5'10
- Solid 5'10
- Liquid 6'
- Solidus 5'11

Comment: I wasn't the DV, but I think, if you add source would help, also, does this add anything to the already existing answers?